# Assign a variable from a range with a specific number format

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code that selects a sheet based on a date from a cell in a different sheet in order to be able to do stuff there. However when I assign the variable it doesn't pick up the proper date format so it doesn't match the sheet name. See below code for clarity:

```
M = Range("A27")
Sheets(M).Select
```

Its ridiculously simple, the date cell A27 is the format of "Mmm-yy", Same with the sheet name that I need should get selected, however VBA pics up the date in a format of "m/d/yyyy" so I get an error "Subscript out of range"

I tried various different things, I can't seem to get how to tell VBA what I want it should read from cell A27.

Comment: `M = format(Range("A27"),"Mmm-yy")`

Comment: Thanks for that!